# With AsciiDoctor, how to pass variables in source and example blocks?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Any one knows how to pass variables `{var}` into `[source]` blocks and example blocks (with `====`) in Asciidoc?

I have tried the following

```
:country: France
:city: Shanghai

[source]
----
print("{country} is a country")
print("{city} is a city")
----

.Example
====
{country} is a country +
{city} is a city
====

.Example with better alignment
====
    {country} is a country
    {city} is a city
====
```

But this is what I get:

[image: result]

Actually the first "example" is working but it is not the ideal solution because:

- It does not have the grey area like other examples
- I need to add a `+` at the end of each line

Looking forward your inputs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1741) you need to switch on attribute replacement in code blocks. You can achieve it with `[subs="attributes"]`complete example should look something like:

```
[source, subs="attributes"]
----
  print("{country} is a country")
  print("{city} is a city")
----

.Example with better alignment
====
[subs="attributes"]
    {country} is a country
    {city} is a city
====
```

Comment: Awesome! Note that you could simplify with `[source, subs="attributes"]`... but the question remains for the "**Example with better alignment**" that uses `====`: any idea?

Comment: Just put [subs="attributes"] under =. (Difficult to read in comment)
    .Example with better alignment
    ====
    [subs="attributes"]
        {country} is a country
        {city} is a city
    ====
Or did I not understand you correct? (Updated answer)